# ¿Qué significado tiene el signo de exclamacion en esta linea #!/usr/bin/env python?

Tags: python

Aunque es un pequeño detalle me gustaria saber porque comenzar esta linea con un signo de exclamacion que hace el ! en #!/usr/bin/env python.

Comment: @César responde en su pregunta el la seccion de notas. Saludos

Answer (score 3):

Se le denomina **Shebang** a los caracteres #! juntos, es cosa de linux para determinar que interprete se va a utilizar seguido de la ruta, en esté caso /usr/bin/env

Es común verlo en los scripts de linux que corre con el interprete bash de la siguiente manera #!/bin/bash